# Server Bootstrap releaseExternalResources stuck in loop

Tags: netty

My issue seems to be related to:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-433

I'm trying to stop my Netty server but this call never returns:

```
serverBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
```

It's looping forever in the ExecutorUtil.terminate method when trying to shutdown the worker ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
org.jboss.netty.util.internal.ExecutorUtil.terminate()
   for (;;) {
       es.shutdownNow(); 
       es.awaitTermination..
   }
```

The problem is I don't have any control over the Client connecting to my Server. Is there a way for the server to force the server to stop and simple close the channel and stop worker threads?

Comment: You sure you're not trying to stop the server using a worker thread ?

Comment: Yes stopping it normally. Believe it is because a Client still has a channel open to my server so I cannot release resources? Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do to ensure that your child channels are closed before you do a releaseAllResources is to register all created child channels in a [ChannelGroup](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html). When you shutdown, you can call [close()](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html#close%28%29) on the ChannelGroup and this will close all the channels in it.

Answer (score 0):

The key part I personally missed according to the [Netty API](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/index.html?org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory.html) is:

```
 public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
     @Override
     public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
         // Add all open channels to the global group so that they are
         // closed on shutdown.
         allChannels.add(e.getChannel());
     }
 }
```

In other words you also have to override a method in your handler.